# Multiple modals with galleries vs. a single dynamic one

Tags: javascript, dom, seo, image-gallery, bootstrap-modal

Lets say we have a long list of posts on a single page. Each of those posts has a hidden `div` with multiple `img` tags inside it. When a user clicks on the post, the images inside the hidden `div` should be showcased in a modal gallery.

Which approach is better SEO-wise - outputting the Bootstrap modal + image gallery markup for each post and unhiding it whenever the user clicks on the post, or having a single hidden modal and `clone()`'ing images to it?

I'm leaning towards the first solution because it is way easier to implement. The second one requires listening to DOM events as I should only initialize the gallery after the images have been cloned to the gallery `div` inside the modal and thus is a bit trickier. Also, I'm not so keen about copying DOM nodes here and there.

Which is the better approach?

**EDIT:** I suppose that it is better to output all images during page load instead of loading them up using AJAX if SEO is important, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose that it is better to output all images during page load instead of loading them up using AJAX if SEO is important, right?

Both methods are equivalent from an SEO perspective for Google, but it may take it a bit more time to index your content for the second method since, it needs to execute Javascript.

However, not all search engines are capable of executing Javascript. Therefore, image tags are all they can eat SEO-wise.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I've ended up choosing the first approach - outputting modals with image gallery markup for each post. The tags are there so I suppose the search engines should be happy now. Javascript only executes to show the modal and manage the image gallery, but the markup is there even without Javascript.